# MySQL change result format of transpose query

Tags: mysql, transpose

I have a table which will be formed dynamically. For eg table data_table15 is as follows,

```
Id     Cost    Product    Quantity
1      3216    Test17     17
2      3217    Test18     18
```

for the above table when I execute this query,

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('select id, ' '''', COLUMN_NAME, ''' col, ', column_name, ' as value from data_table15') separator '  union all ' ) INTO @sql FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'data_table15' and column_name <> 'id';
set @sql = CONCAT(@sql,' order by 1,2');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

The result is,

```
1    Product   Test17
1    Cost      3216
1    Quantity  17
2    Product   Test18
2    Cost      3217
2    Quantity  18
```

But I expect a result like this,

```
Id        1          2
Product   Test17     Test18
Cost      3216       3217
Quantity  17         18
```

How can I change the query to achieve this?

Comment: This isn't going to scale well for a large number of IDs.  Do you really need this output?

Comment: Yes it is taking longer time but is there a way to achieve this or any alternative suggestions please.

Comment: @Shyamala as Tim suggested it won't scale much its better if you do this kind of stuff in your application code Mysql isn't good for this

Comment: Ok agreedt, I tried a maximum of 7 lakh rows and 200 columns table for which the time taken was close to 45 minutes which is very much longer. But the query execution time shown by sql was 11 min and 25 seconds

Comment: Thanks for your help @MKhalidJunaid